A sum of integrals representation involving $\zeta(4)$
Do we have the following $\zeta(4)$ representation included in the mathematical literature?
$$\zeta(4)$$
$$=\frac{32}{45}\int_0^1  x  \arctan^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \operatorname{arctanh}^3(x) \textrm{d}x+\frac{16}{45} \pi ^2 \int_0^1 x \arctan^2(x) \operatorname{arctanh}(x) \textrm{d}x$$
$$-\frac{32}{45} \pi  \int_0^1 x \arctan^3(x) \operatorname{arctanh}(x)\textrm{d}x+\frac{16}{45} \int_0^1 x \arctan^4(x) \operatorname{arctanh}(x) \textrm{d}x.$$
How about other similar results? Thank you!

$\zeta(4)=\dfrac{\pi^4}{90}$

\begin{align}\zeta(4)=\frac{1}{6}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 x}{x-1}dx\end{align}

@FDP haha, okay! :-)
